# Implementing IDocHostUIHandler.FilterDataObject in C#

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control, com-interop

I'm trying to add a HTML capable editor to a WPF application. The obvious choice is using the default WebBrowser control, and putting its document into "design mode". So far, so good.

Now, it's getting tricky, because I need to be able to intercept content that get pasted into the editor from the clipboard to make sure it is in a usable format. For example, when pasting a snippet from a Word document containing an image, the image is represented by a piece of Office XML that the Browser control doesn't understand, so I would need to replace that with a simple <img> tag before it is inserted into the document.

After realizing that there is no way to accomplish this on the pure WPF level, I had to drill down to the ActiveX component that the WebBrowser control is only a wrapper for. It appears as if my problem (and some others that I am also facing, but that are not relevant for this question) could be solved by providing a custom implementation of the `IDocHostUIHandler` interface.

This interface contains a method called `FilterDataObject` which apparently gets called whenever a paste operation takes place, giving the implementation a chance to inspect and, if necessary, change the data received from the clipboard by the browser.

For reference, here's my the definition of the method in the IDocHostUIHandler interface:

```
[ComImport]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
[Guid("bd3f23c0-d43e-11cf-893b-00aa00bdce1a")]
public interface IDocHostUIHandler {
    // ...
    [PreserveSig]
    int FilterDataObject(
        [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] object pDO,
        [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out object ppDORet
    );
}
```

The COM object that gets passed in can be cast to `System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IDataObject`, and works fine for accessing the clipboard contents. But when I actually try to return a replacement IDataObject through the out parameter, I get an access violation exception.

For example, a naive attempt to simply return a new instance of the existing class `System.Windows.DataObject` (which also implements `...ComTypes.IDataObject`, so my hope was that the CLR would be able to properly marshal it out-of-the-box) like this ...

```
public class MyDocHostUIHandler : IDocHostUIHandler {
    // ...
    public int FilterDataObject(object pDO, out object ppDORet) {
        ppDORet = new System.Windows.DataObject("Text", "New Clipboard Content!");
        return S_OK; // S_OK means that the data object has been replaced
    }
}
```

... doesn't work (AccessViolationException as soon as I try to paste anything into the editor).

Has anyone ever done something like this? What might I be doing wrong? Is the definition of my ComImport-ed interface broken (it was pretty difficult to find a version on the web that actually works -  at least some of the time - to begin with)? Is what I am trying to do even possible from managed code?

Comment: don't know what the default marshaller is doing, but did you try detach the COM interface via Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject instead?

Comment: I suspect the problem is the double pointer which is defined in the method declaration of the original com interface for the out parameter:

    `HRESULT FilterDataObject(IDataObject *pDO, IDataObject **ppDORet);`

I'm not sure how to properly marshal that.

Comment: I even tried turning `ppDORet` into an `IntPtr` and then using `Marshal.WriteIntPtr` to write the result of `Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject` to it myself, but I still get the same access violation exception.

Comment: Try  [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
 int FilterDataObject(System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IDataObject pDO, out System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IDataObject ppDORet);
}

Comment: Weird. I was sure that was one of the first things I tried (because it seemed like the most obvious) and that it did not work at the time. But I just tried it, and it does work after all. COM Interop really is like black magic sometimes... Either way, thanks a lot. PS: You might want to rewrite your comment as an answer, so I can accept and upvote it like it deserves :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] int FilterDataObject(System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IDataObject pDO, out System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IDataObject ppDORet); }

If you have problem generating signatures for COM interfaces, often you can [generate from Windows SDK tools using midl and tlbimp](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/advhost.aspx).